# Analytics v4 ga:transactions number not less than 6

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get data on keywords, transactions and ad clicks using Analytics reporting API v4, but I am seeing that number of transactions jumps from 0 to 6. So basically number of transactions is not less than 6 if I discard zeros. Is it a normal behavior or there is some hard coded limit on the google server side? Here is a body of the message (I am using Python). The `ga:transactions` is 0, 6, and then continues.

```
service = build(
     'analytics', 
     'v4', 
     credentials=credentials,
     cache_discovery=False
)    

 body = {
    'viewId': view_id,
    'dateRanges': [{
        'startDate': start_date,
        'endDate': end_date
    }],
    'dimensions': [
        {'name': 'ga:adMatchedQuery'},
        {'name': 'ga:adDestinationUrl'}
    ],
    'metrics': [
        {'expression': 'ga:adClicks'},
        {'expression': 'ga:transactions'}
    ],
    'samplingLevel': 'LARGE',
    'includeEmptyRows': 'true'
}

res = service.reports().batchGet(
    body={
        'reportRequests': body
    }
).execute()
```

Comment: Your results are probably sampled. Can you check, if this happened? If yes, could you try a shorter date range to get unsampled data?

Comment: @kgrg I used samplingLevel: LARGE to get higher precision, but it didn't help. Thanks for advice! Initially my time span was 4 months and I changed it to 15 days and more transactions appeared :) Now I see 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on.

Comment: When you scan a date range that contains more than 500K sessions - sampling kicks in. There are measures to handle this. If you query 1 day at a time and append all the results you have probably fixed your issue. Just beware that not all metrics can be summed across dates. E.g Users metric. You can easily sum the adclicks and transactions. If you don't want to do this kind of extraction yourself. Take a look and supermetrics.com (simple up to 9 dimension datasets) or scitylana.com (big 100+ dimensions - bi ready datasets)